# Как обратиться к внешнему "this" из обработчика события?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Имеется такой конструктор:

```
function Options() {
    this.property = '';

    $('elem').on('click', function(){
        this.property = 'str'; // попытка обращения к внешнему this
    });
}
```

но внутри обработчика свой this, как мне обратиться к this.property?

Comment: Сохранить в другую переменную и обращаться к ней.

Comment: Или использовать стрелочную функцию, если внутренний this не нужен.

Comment: Тип свойства примитивный, копирование в другую переменную будет по значению. А мне нужно именно значение свойства изменить, а не другой переменной. Или я чего-то недопонимаю. По поводу стрелок можно пояснить, как это сделать?

Comment: `var that = this; ... that.property = "str"` сохранять в переменную надо не свойство, а this

Comment: Да, точно, так и есть! Спасибо!)

Comment: Вместо `function(){...}` можно использовать `()=>{...}`.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема заключается в потере контекста.
Для решение тебе нужно обработчик события вынести в отдельный метод, а потом прибайндить к нему контекст.
Вот пример:

```
function Options() {
    this.property = '';
    this.clickHandler = function(){
        this.property = 'str';
    };

    $('elem').on('click', this.clickHandler.bind(this));
}
```

Или же ты можешь использовать стрелочную функцию вместо обычной. В таком случаи потери контексту не будет:

```
function Options() {
    this.property = '';

    $('elem').on('click', () => {
        this.property = 'str';
    });
}
```